# Samuelson Consumption loan paper and Overlapping Generations

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics

The famous Samuelson paper on consumption loan and interest rates is a bit odd in my opinion. I wanted to understand it a bit better. The paper outline 3 generations.

Youth that produce 1 unit.
The middle aged that produce 1 unit.
The old retirees that produce nothing.
The generations consume $C_i$. Samuelson shows that equilibrium allocation is not Pareto optimal. Samuelson seems to make a few assumptions of the utility functions $U(C_1, C_2, C_3)$. One there is no time preference for consumption. The utility is symmetric in its arguments. First of I was a bit intrigued by what he means by symmetry? Does he mean $U(C_1 + \epsilon, C_2 - \epsilon, C_3) = U(C_1, C_2, C_3)$?

In all honesty I did not quite understand the paper. Samuelson goes on the show that there the interest rate of exchange is either $0$ or the rate at which the population grows.

The issue I have is two fold. 1) Pareto optimality. I did not quite understand his reasoning as to why the equilibrium allocation is not Pareto optimal. If everyone consumes their current production $(1, 1, 0)$ and given that agents prefer to consume more than less this is the optimal allocation. They would perhaps prefer to consume something during old age, and would that mean $U(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3}) >= U(1 - x, 1 - x, 2 x)$ for all $x \ne \frac{1}{3}$. 2) What if the young and the old do not produce. The only production is middle aged. In that case the middle aged loan to the young a $\frac{1}{3}$ pay back $\frac{1}{3}$ and consume $\frac{1}{3}$. Would that be Pareto optimal in the Samuelson sense?